# Django + Gunicorn + Nginx: Bad Request (400) in Debug=True

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to run my server with Django, nginx and gunicorn. On the development Server, everything went fine. But on the production server, gunicorn always returns a Bad Request (400).

I'm aware that I need to set my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable, and I did. I tried the correct domain, an asterisk, or even setting DEBUG to True. But still, it's always Bad Request (400).

Here is my nginx-config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /static {
        alias /home/username/sites/sub.domain.example.com/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

My `wsgi-prod.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings_prod")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The `settings_prod.py` file (shortened):

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]
```

I start gunicorn the following way (with virtualenv):

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 app.wsgi_prod:application
```

When I start the server with `manage.py runserver --settings=app.settings_prod` , the site is accessible. gunicorn's error log shows nothing, and the access log only shows the 400. The static content does work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should tell Nginx to pass the host to Gunicorn like this:

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
```

Additionally I would pass these values (example) also so you have access to the IP of the request:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Please also check your Nginx Logs if you haven´t done so.
I hope this helps.

EDIT:
Try also to set set server name like:

```
server_name     your_domain.com www.your_domain.com
```

Last but not least try to set your environment like this (solution in this case):

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "app.settings_prod"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. The nginx logs just show the 400. I'm really clueless here, because I did the same thing on the development server (including gunicorn) and everything works.

Comment: Try to set the domain in server name... ??

Comment: Are you running multiple sites on this server? Then you would have to set the environ like os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "app.settings_prod" in your wsgi file...

Comment: That did it! I am only running one site one the server, but tried setting the environ, just in case. And it works. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: I was experiencing this issue as well and the three `proxy_set_header` settings fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
```